# What corruption is indicated by WinDbg and !chkimg?

Tags: windbg, memory-corruption

I am having often `BSODs` and WinDbg report similar corruption for most of them

```
4: kd> !chkimg -lo 50 -d !nt
    fffff80177723e6d-fffff80177723e6e  2 bytes - nt!MiPurgeZeroList+6d
    [ 80 fa:00 e9 ]
2 errors : !nt (fffff80177723e6d-fffff80177723e6e)
```

and

```
CHKIMG_EXTENSION: !chkimg -lo 50 -d !nt
    fffff8021531ae6d-fffff8021531ae6e  2 bytes - nt!MiPurgeZeroList+6d
    [ 80 fa:00 aa ]
2 errors : !nt (fffff8021531ae6d-fffff8021531ae6e)
```

What does it mean? What with what is compared and how it can be that corruption is similar? Does it explicitly indicates RAM problem?

**UPDATE**

What do these numbers mean? `fffff80177723e6d` and `fffff8021531ae6d`? What does it mean, that endings conincide?

What does the following code mean: `nt!MiPurgeZeroList+6d`?

Comment: MiPurgeZeroList is a function of the memory manager to clean memory to move memory pages to Free or Zero memory list

Answer (score 1):

I already answered this on superuser.com. Windbg downloads the original Exe/DLLs from the Symbol Server and now the [chkimg command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) detects corruption in the images of executable files by comparing them to the copy on a symbol store.

> All sections of the file are compared, except for sections that are
>   discardable, that are writeable, that are not executable, that have
>   "PAGE" in their name, or that are from INITKDBG. You can change this
>   behavior can by using the -ss, -as, or -r switches.
>
> `!chkimg` displays any mismatch between the image and the file as an
>   image error, with the following exceptions:
>
> - Addresses that are occupied by the Import Address Table (IAT) are not checked.
> - Certain specific addresses in Hal.dll and Ntoskrnl.exe are not checked, because certain changes occur when these sections are loaded.
>     To check these addresses, include the -nospec option.
> - If the byte value 0x90 is present in the file, and if the value 0xF0 is present in the corresponding byte of the image (or vice
>     versa), this situation is considered a match. Typically, the symbol
>     server holds one version of a binary that exists in both uniprocessor
>     and multiprocessor versions. On an x86-based processor, the lock
>     instruction is 0xF0, and this instruction corresponds to a nop (0x90)
>     instruction in the uniprocessor version. If you want !chkimg to
>     display this pair as a mismatch, set the -noplock option.

If the RAM is fine, check the HDD / HDD cables for errors (disk diag tool and run chkdsk to detect and fix NTFS issues). You can also connect the HDD to  different SATA port on the mainboard.

Comment: If `!chkimg` shows difference between image and a DISK file, then how can it be, that `DSIM` sees no difference? May be `!chkimg` compares with MEMORY?

Comment: P.S. I already performed all possible manipulations with existing cables; I wish to understand debugging topic here

Comment: it compares the files it found in the dump to clean images from symbol server. if the HDD cable is bad, it could be corrupted during read from disk into memory

Comment: But dump represents memory. So it compares from DUMP with from online IMAGE. And mismatch means it was an error during file load into memory at the moment before BSOD. And this corresponds to the check of DSIM, which compares DISK with IMAGE, right?

Comment: Today I put totally new cables.

Comment: I'm not sure that the comments above make sense. It seems to me that bad disk cables would case read errors when reading from disk which should be reported in the event log. The OS wouldn't just read errors from disk and put the wrong data in memory. It checks for errors and reports these instead. DISM (not DSIM) would report differences and correct these if the image on disk were corrupted. Instead, I would suspect that a buffer overflow or other bug in code caused the image in memory to be overwritten inadvertently. But then I'm no expert in this and was hoping to find confirmation here.